# Air Sqlite Date in YYYY/MM/DD HH:MM Format

Tags: apache-flex, sqlite, air

While I was playing with Air Sqlite, I got some trouble in saving Date in the Database

```
INSERT INTO tblUserComments (comment_text, comment_cat,comment_date,parent_id) VALUES('"+bubbleText.text+"','"+chosenCat+"',DATETIME('now', 'localtime'),'"+_parentId+"')
```

store the comment_date in the following format

2455783.2596296296 instead of 2011/08/09 18:13.

How can I save the Date Data as YYYY/MM/DD HH:MM?

Thank you so much.

Comment: What trouble did you have?  Is the issue with saving the date;or displaying it for format?  Wouldn't you just want to use the database value as the value into a new Date Object and then use a DateFormatter to display it?

Comment: How is the table structured?  Is the comment_date column set as DATE?

Comment: @J_A_X, yes it is. comment_date column is set as DATE.

Comment: @Flextras.com, For example when I try to do "SELECT SELECT * FROM tblUserComments WHERE comment_date<='2011/08/24'", I do not get appropriate records.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reading up on it, your column can't be set as DATE, since there isn't such a type in SQLite.  To quote the dev manual:

> SQLite does not have a storage class set aside for storing dates
>   and/or times. Instead, the built-in Date And Time Functions of SQLite
>   are capable of storing dates and times as TEXT, REAL, or INTEGER
>   values

I would recommend you save the date as an INTEGER of epoc time, then you can do the conversion to whatever either when selecting the rows or within the code.  I personally prefer to use the Date class to convert it properly depending on timezone.  ie. `var date:Date = new Date(epocTime);`

Comment: But, AIR compiler did not throw any error when I use the following:CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tblUserComments ( comment_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, comment_text TEXT, comment_cat TEXT,comment_date DATETIME,parent_id INTEGER)

Comment: The compiler wouldn't throw errors for that, but maybe during the execution.  Or maybe SQLite just defaults it to String.  Either way, it should be an INTEGER.

Answer (score 1):

use parameters instead because it regulates many issues automatically and set the type of your column in sqlite to DATE and assign it a new Date() object directly or assign it a string value in the following format:

```
private function dateToMySqlFormat(date:Date = null):String
{
    var formattedDate:DateFormatter = new DateFormatter();
    formattedDate.formatString = "YYYY-MM-DD JJ:NN:SS";

    if(date == null) date = new Date;

    return formattedDate.format(date);
}
```

that should work